# How to get zip files from a text file and then write the contents into another text file?

Tags: python, loops, file, zip

I am trying to use three files in which the first is the text file that contains the names of 3 different zip files. I then want to open those 3 files and write their contents into a separate text file. I have the pseudocode for this program but I am unable to figure out what to do. I have some code but I don't know if it is correct for this program. I am not very advanced in python yet so I would like to run this code using concept that are mostly in my code or easier code that can help me get a walk through of how to make and run this program.

Pseudocode:
Input File – List of zip file names with location
Read each line from the input file, read the contents of the zip file and write it to the output file
Output File – print the list of the files/contents inside the zip file

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import zipfile
write_file = open('file.txt' , "w")

input_file = open('C:\\Users\\Tanish L\\OneDrive\\InputReadFile.txt','r')

i = 0

readfile = input_file.readlines()
a = True
for line in readfile:
   while a == True:
      print(readfile[0:i])
      i = int(i) + 1
      if i > len(readfile):
    a = False
file_names = zipfile.ZipFile(#file line from input_file,'r')
for name in file_names.namelist():
    write_file.write('%s' % (name) + "\n")
 
 
 

file_names.close()

write_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import zipfile
write_file = open('file.txt' , "w")

input_file = open('C:\\Users\\Tanish L\\OneDrive\\InputReadFile.txt','r')

i = 0

readfile = input_file.readlines()

for line in readfile:
   f = zipfile.ZipFile(line.rstrip())
   for name in f.namelist():
      write_file.write(name + "\n") 

f.close()
write_file.close()
```

**Explanation:**

You already loop over the lines in readfile (array) with the for loop and don't need a counter controlled while loop as well.

You then open the zipfile with the filename of that line (rstrip removes the newline '\n' at the end).

Then loop over the files in the zip file using namelist, and write that to your write file.

Comment: I tried running your code and received an error for file_names.close() because file_names was undefined. Do I need to add my code which has the variable for file_names?

Comment: @Tan7 Sorry, I changed the variable name in the declaration and not below, I haven't tested it as I don't have a setup with zip files like yours, but I think now that I edited it, it should work